# no audio on windows guest after installing vbox guest additions

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

Ive posted this here because im not sure whether its a windows or linux problem, so feel free to correct me. Ive installed windows 7 on a virtual box vm running on ubuntu, and i have then installed the virtual box guest additions. Everything seems to have worked, except for the audio, windows is reporting it does not have any audio output devices installed.

This is where im not sure whether its a windows or linux problem.

In my vm settings ive got audio set as:

ALSA audio driver and ICH 97 as the controller. Ive installed vbox additions 3.2.8

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If following [Oli](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13511/no-audio-on-windows-guest-after-installing-vbox-guest-additions/13517#13517)'s answer updating VirtualBox or selecting PulseAudio does not help you may have missing [AC97 drivers](http://www.realtek.com.tw/Downloads/downloadsCheck.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=23&PFid=23&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false) in Windows7. For details see this thread in [VirtualBox forum](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=14155&start=0).

Answer (score 4):

Use PulseAudio (the sound system Ubuntu uses directly).

[image: Pulseaudio in VirtualBox]

If you don't have that available, I suggest you update VirtualBox to a newer version.

Comment: Ive tried switching it to pulse audio, still doesnt show up in windows im afraid.